# Java-script Method not calling when page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to bind dropdown using jquery and ajax and I'm trying call method when page load. Below my code

```
   $(function () {

            getCategoryDetails();
            getCountryDetails();
    });
```

Below my get Category details. It work's like empty drop-down and assigning parameter value and block UI and calling drop-down Category Appender method

```
function getCategoryDetails() {

    try {

        $('#ddlCategory').empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Select Category</option>');
        categoryReq.PageIndex = 1;
        categoryReq.objDetails.OrganizationID = LoggedinUserDetails.ID;
        categoryReq.objDetails.OpType = 1;
        blockUI();
        dropdownCategoryAppender();
    }
    catch (err) {
        messageProvider(0, err);
        unBlockUI();
    }
}

function dropdownCategoryAppender() {
    try {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/pages/AddContact.aspx/GetCategoryDetails',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify({ 'obj': JSON.stringify(categoryReq) }),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {

                categoryRes = data.d;
                categoryReq.IsMoreRecords = categoryRes.IsMoreRecords;

                if (categoryRes.ReturnID >= 1) {

                    var ddl = $("[id*=ddlCategory]");

                    $.each(categoryRes.objDetails, function () {
                        ddl.append($("<option></option>").val(this.ID).html(this.Name));

                    });
                    unBlockUI();
                }
                else {
                    messageProvider(0, categoryRes.ReturnMsg);
                    unBlockUI();
                }

                if (categoryReq.IsMoreRecords) {
                    categoryReq.PageIndex++;
                    blockUI();
                    dropdownCategoryAppender();
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                messageProvider(0, textStatus + ', ' + errorThrown);
                unBlockUI();
            }
        });

    }
    catch (err) {
        messageProvider(0, err);
        unBlockUI();
    }
}
```

Above mentioned methods are worked properly but below methods is not worked.
I am fetching the country data then I trying to bind these data into drop-down but binding process skip.

```
function getCountryDetails() {

    try {

        $('#ddlCountry').empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Select Country</option>');
        countryReq.PageIndex = 1;
        countryReq.objDetails.OpType = 1;
        blockUI();
        dropdownCountryAppender();
    }
    catch (err) {
        messageProvider(0, err);
    }
}

function dropdownCountryAppender() {
    try {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/pages/AddContact.aspx/GetCountryDetails',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify({ 'obj': JSON.stringify(countryReq) }),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {

                countryRes = data.d;

                countryReq.IsMoreRecords = countryRes.IsMoreRecords;

                if (countryRes.ReturnID >= 1) {

                    var ddl = $("[id*=ddlCountry]");

                    $.each(countryRes.objDetails, function () {
                        ddl.append($("<option></option>").val(this.ID).html(this.Name));
                    });

                    unBlockUI();
                }
                else {
                    messageProvider(0, countryRes.ReturnMsg);
                    unBlockUI();
                }

                if (countryReq.IsMoreRecords) {
                    countryReq.PageIndex++;
                    blockUI();
                    dropdownCountryAppender();
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                messageProvider(0, textStatus + ', ' + errorThrown);
                unBlockUI();
            }
        });

    }
    catch (err) {
        messageProvider(0, err);
        unBlockUI();
    }
}
```

Any one has any idea about this please help me.

Comment: Did you used `document ready`?

Comment: I am using this ( $(function () {

            getCategoryDetails();
            getCountryDetails();
    }); )

Comment: you need to fire the function at page load ready state using `document ready`

Comment: Check browser console window, also post screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
```

See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp). Easy to Google

Comment: I have multiple functions dude

Comment: Google is your friend! "onload multiple functions" http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3724571/Using-Multiple-JavaScript-Onload-Functions.htm

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```
<body onload="myFunction();myFunction1();myFunction2()">
```